Flutter Universal link fails to open app on App Store
After setting up the uni-links plugin in Flutter, everything works perfectly on Android but iOS only works when I have the app installed, if the app is not installed, it leads to the App Store as expected but displays an error message.
App Store Error

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
